# Import error for csv_serializer in AWS Sagemaker

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker

I am not able to run

```
from sagemaker.predictor import csv_serializer
```

Following is the import error I am getting.

ImportError: cannot import name 'csv_serializer' from 'sagemaker.predictor' (/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/python3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sagemaker/predictor.py)

I tried running following command on notebook instance in sagemaker.

```
!{sys.executable} -m pip install sagemaker==1.72.0 -U
```

Answer (score 2):

Did you try restarting the kernel after running the pip install command?

Note that `csv_serializer` was deprecated in v2 of the SDK, so updating your usage is the correct long-term solution. See [v2 documentation](https://github.com/aws/sagemaker-python-sdk/blob/master/doc/v2.rst#deprecations) for the new usage.

Answer (score 0):

Update the sagemaker to latest version `pip install --upgrade sagemaker`. And then try the following steps to get CSV Serializer.

Import the following

```py
from sagemaker.serializers import CSVSerializer
```

Usage

```py
xgb_predictor.serializer = CSVSerializer()
```

Reference: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/ex1-model-deployment.html